# WordPress setup page is not showing

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to setup Wordpress manually.

First, I created the database and user and connected them both with all privileges. 
Next, I downloaded the Wordpress setup file and added the database name, username and password to the wp-config.php file and uploaded the Wordpress file to the file manager under public_html.

But when I visit my website, it's still not showing the setup wizard. I also tried manually entering the URL - www.example.com/wp-admin/install.php, but it redirects to me the same page (page image is below)

[this the page i am getting instead of wordpress setup wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuZY8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshot, you haven't set up your Wix account to use your domain name. If you have, was this done recently? DNS propagation can take 24 - 48 hours.

If the domain name and server are connected, then you need to make sure all WP files are uploaded. You should have downloaded a zip file to your computer. Unzip the file, then FTP the entire folder inside your public_html folder.

Once that is done, then you can proceed with the installation.

The problem is, Wix has their own software and blog features. You will need to set up WP on a subdomain. You can learn how to set up a subdomain [through Wix here](https://support.wix.com/en/article/connecting-a-subdomain-to-an-external-resource-eg-a-blog) and how to install the [WP to a subdomain here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-subdomain/).

The biggest problem, though, is Wix. You would be a lot better off getting stand alone hosting such as SiteGround, A2hosting, etc. If you are looking for cheap hosting, HostGator and Green Geeks are decent enough.

Comment: Thanks @JT Pledger , but the issue resolves automatically.

Comment: Then it was just a matter of DNS propagation. Adding a new domain and pointing it to the hosting server can take anywhere from a few minutes to 48 hours. Glad it is resolved.